# Merging Python nested dictionaries with mergeable keys on different levels

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, nested

I searched for a solution to this problem for a while, but all solutions assume that the joinable keys are in the same nested level of the dictionaries.

To make it short, having these two dicts:

```
dict1 = {'Head': 
            {'Face': 
                {'Eyes': 
                    {'Eyebrows': {}, 
                     'Eyelids': 
                        {'Eyelashes': {}
                        }
                    }, 
                 'Nose': {}, 
                 'Mouth': {}
                }
            }
        }
dict2 = {'Eyes': 
            {'Eyebrows': {}, 
             'Eyelids': 
                {'Eyelashes': {}
                }
            }
        }
```

I want the following:

```
dict3 = {'Head': 
            {'Face': 
                {'Eyes': 
                    {'Eyebrows': {}, 
                     'Eyelids': 
                        {'Eyelashes': {}
                        }
                    },         
                 'Nose': {}, 
                 'Mouth': {}
                }
            }
        }
```

As you see, the key "Eyes" should be the merging point in this little example, and it is on the third level of the tree in dict1 and on the first level in dict2. The dictionaries may have overlapping for all the keys/values (at different levels, like in the 'Eyes' case), or no overlapping at all, but I need to avoid duplicates as well.

The point is, I will find that either one dictionary is already included in the other or they will not overlap at all. I'm trying to "prune" a giant tree keeping only certain nodes based on a term search (pure string search). The problem is that some of the nodes (and derivated, deeper nodes) may include some of the others, but sometimes they may not coincide at all. Think of it as a tree/nested dictionary of your body. You could search "cell", find a big node called "blood cells", which include other nodes like "coagulation cells", "transport cells" or "protective cells". Also, in another branch of the main tree, you may find "bone cells", for instance. All of them would be retrieved in the search, some of them may include others ("coagulation", "transport" or "protective" would be inside "blood cells") but some others may be separate from that tree ("bone cells"). I want them to be in the same global nested tree.

How can I merge several dictionaries in this case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is no before/after difference of `dict1` to `dict3` - wich makes it a not as nice example. What did you try to merge your data ( [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) ? Also: please provide real data.

Comment: @PatrickArtner You're right, it's not a good example and I actually had some troubles writing the question, it's quite tricky. I updated my post with the general idea of what I want to do, maybe it's more understandable than focusing on the examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the level at which they intersect, you'd have to do something like a depth-first search tree to confirm that dictionary 2 is not in dictionary 1, then add them both at the top level.

Find the level, and then perform your dictionary merge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple recursive function to update your dictionaries (node: I added key-value pairs to the empty dictionaries in your input, to reflect the actual changes being made by the code below):

```
d = {'Head': {'Face': {'Eyes': {'Eyebrows': {}, 'Eyelids': {'Eyelashes': {}}}, 'Nose': {}, 'Mouth': {}}}}
dict2 = {'Eyes': 
           {'Eyebrows': {"color":'brown'}, 
             'Eyelids': 
            {'Eyelashes': {"type":"long", "color":"black"}
            }
        }
 }
def update_dict(d, update_with):
   if not any(i in update_with for i in d):
     return {a:update_dict(b, update_with) if isinstance(b, dict) else b for a, b in d.items()}
   return {a:update_dict(b, update_with if a not in update_with else update_with[a]) if isinstance(b, dict) and b \
       else update_with.get(a, b) for a, b in d.items()}
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(update_dict(d, dict2), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
"Head": {
    "Face": {
        "Eyes": {
            "Eyebrows": {
                "color": "brown"
            },
            "Eyelids": {
                "Eyelashes": {
                    "type": "long",
                    "color": "black"
                }
             }
         },
         "Nose": {},
         "Mouth": {}
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks nice!